# Size of an OpenGL context

Tags: linux, opengl

Is there a way to get a size of an opengl context? Or at least to estimate it's size? If yes, how?

---

I have an application in glut, which creates several windows. Since glut doesn't share opengl context between windows, every window is going to create new. Now, I am trying to reduce needed memory, since it is for an embedded system. But if the opengl context is small enough to neglect it, then I am not going to see big reduction in memory usage.

---

I have found [this patch](http://graphics.tudelft.nl/~paul/glut.html) to create windows with shared opengl context :

> A small addendum for Windows users (by Misbah Qidwai): I added this subroutine to glut_win.c. I use this routine to call wglSharedLists()

```
//MQ
/* CENTRY */
GLXContext APIENTRY
glutGetWindowRenderContext(int win)
{
  GLUTwindow *window;

  if (win < 1 || win > __glutWindowListSize) {
    __glutWarning("glutSetWindow attempted on bogus window.");
    return NULL;                                              
  }
  window = __glutWindowList[win - 1];
  if (!window) {
    __glutWarning("glutSetWindow attempted on bogus window.");
    return NULL;                                              
  }
  return window->renderCtx;
}
```

Comment: What "embedded system" offers GLUT? Also, how do you define the "size" of the context?

Comment: @NicolBolas I am working on a custom embedded system with a pentium CPU, running a fedora 15 with some RT patches. The size of the context is (I guess) a memory needed for an opengl context. The question is : how to get it or at least estimate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A OpenGL context is an abstract thing. The amount of data backing a particular context can be as small as a pointer, or as big as a few megabytes. The context itself is not some kind of data structure, it's merely a handle shared by your program and the graphics system so that each other "knows" what the other is talking about.

The only way to know in a particular configuration is to measure it.

Comment: I was afraid of such answer. Is there a way to measure it? And do you know what influence it' size? Amount and size of textures, lists, vertices, etc?

Comment: Start the program and watch it using a tool like htop to get a coarse overview. For detailed measurement use valgrind to collect statistics about its memory profile. Every OpenGL object consumes some memory, i.e. everything you allocate with a `glGen…()` call. In case of data holding objects (textures, VBOs, PBOs, shaders) the amount of memory consumed depends on the data. FBOs and VAOs are abstract objects, their memory consumption also depends on their parameters but within much tighter boundaries.